# Getting the exact and closest Search using CONTAINS/CONTAINSTABLE in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table that contains 30 000+ records named as `ProductCodes` that contains a column '`Value`'.

I have made a query that'll return the records matching and containing a passed String using CONTAINS.

```
Select TOP 5 * from ProductCodes
WHERE CONTAINS(Value,'"pepper*"')
```

It does return the records contains 'Pepper' e.g. Pepper and Bayleaf, Peppermint, Dr. Pepper etc.
I also have an exact record that only contains the exact string, 'Pepper' which is displayed in the mid of the results. I only need to select the TOP 5 of the records and also the exacting match of passed string.

I also tried to use the CONTAINSTABLE

```
SELECT Value, RANK FROM
ProductCodes PC
INNER JOIN
CONTAINSTABLE(ProductCodes,Value,N'pepper') AS KEY_TBL
ON PC.Value = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY RANK DESC
```

I tried using a `WHERE rank = 1000` which I read somewhere that's the rank of the closest match but as I figured out the rank of the record 'Pepper' is 128 and phrases that have more than 1 word match have a higher rank.

I am fairly new to using `FREETEXT and Semantics` so I am still learning on it. How can I take the exact match and 'partial' match in my TOP 5? TIA

### edit:

I have added a `UNION ALL` query where it first selects the equal record and combining it with my `CONTAINS` query.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM (
 SELECT TOP 5 * From ProductCodes 
 WHERE Value = 'pepper'
 UNION ALL 
 Select TOP 5 * from ProductCodes
 WHERE CONTAINS(Value,'"pepper*"')
) as Value
```

Now, I can get the exacting match and partial match but wonder how it'll make my query slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latest query allows the same row to be returned twice. Also it,'s possible to limit the results considering a predefined weight for the match in order to get a more relevant output.

You should get a more precise result with this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 10000 AS RANK,
        P.id, 
        P.value 
    FROM ProductCodes P
    WHERE P.value = 'pepper'

    UNION

    SELECT k.RANK,
        P.id, 
        P.value 
    FROM ProductCodes P
        INNER JOIN  
          CONTAINSTABLE(ProductCodes, value, 'ISABOUT (pepper WEIGHT(0.2), 
            "pepper*" WEIGHT(0.1))',  
            5) AS K  
          ON P.id = K.[KEY]
    WHERE value <> 'pepper'
) 
SELECT TOP (5) RANK, id, value
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RANK DESC;
```

---

**References:**

[Search for words or phrases using weighted values (Weighted Term)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15#Weighted_Term)

[Examples of Using RANK to Limit Search Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/limit-search-results-with-rank?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I find this more accurate in solving my problem but does using a Recursive in the database have any effect on the overall system performance?

Comment: @bish-cuit, a **Common Table Expression (CTE)** is not recursive by itself, it can only become recursive if you call it on the 2nd query. You can check it on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267459/recursive-parent-child-location-relationship-cache-as-view/267486#267486) where I actually used a recursive CTE. Notice that on the query right under the `UNION ALL` there's a `INNER JOIN CTE_Locations` which is the name of the defined CTE. That self reference makes the CTE recursive. The way I used the CTE to answer your question it works just like a temporary table.